# Бесконечная жизнь обьекта в WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, autofac

В проекте .NET WebApi используется api сторонней библиотеки, которая при первой инициализации выполняется очень долго при первом запросе к нашему серверу, последующие запросы быстро. Подгружаем ее в global.asax через autofac контейнер (di/ioc) Проблема в том, что в режиме простоя (когда долго нет запросов) обьект библиотеки умирает и заново инициализация происходит при новом запросе (опять долгое время).Как заставить обьект жить вечно, на протяжении пока сервер (iis) запущен!! Класс библиотеки реализует IDisposable() , но сами в коде ни close ни dispose не вызываем!

Comment: пробовали настроить пул приложения, чтобы он работал в невыгружаемом режиме? Должно помочь.

Comment: мм....это со стороны проекта или iis делается?

Comment: со стороны IIS, он имеет привычку выгружать приложение, когда к нему не обращаются, при дефолтных настройках

Comment: пожалуйста, подскажите где эта настройка !!! Видна только настройка времени ожиданий подключений! -Но это не то

Comment: спасибо, нашел где настраивается! Сейчас проверять буду!

Comment: у меня сервис уже 2 года работает вот с [такими](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USt7L.png) настройками пула

Comment: а по производительности норм? память не скапливается? или GC делает свое дело?

Comment: Это все от вашего кода зависит. У меня все работает как часы.

Comment: @tym32167 может в ответ перенести? С меня, если что, картинка с русскоязычным вариантом интерфейса.

Comment: @rdorn нет времени писать полноценный ответ. Можете сами его накатать или я не выходных сделаю, если не забуду.